# Cut command not returning correct output

Tags: shell, cut

**Scenario**

I am trying to use cut command to get the 4th field from a file that has the redirected output of a df command. But it's only cutting and returning the 1st field for some reason.

```
df -kh -B 1g /ws/abc-Location03 > file1.txt
cut -d" " -f4 file1.txt
```

**Output of my df command**

```
Filesystem           1G-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
abc5-xyz04c:/root_vdm_6/t2local24/abc-Location03
                       500       408        93  82% /ws/abc-Location03
```

**Output of my cut command**

```
abc5-xyz04c:/root_vdm_6/t2local24/abc-Location03
```

Basically, it's cutting just the 1st field and returning it, instead of the 4th field. I 'd like to know what it is I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` instead:

```
df -kh -B 1g /ws/abc-Location03 | awk '{print $4}'
```

Comment: Thanks.. I added one more to your answer however. I did df -kh -B 1g /ws/abc-Location03 | awk '{print $3}' > file1.txt. But any idea why the cut din't work as expected?

Comment: Because `cut` cannot handle multiple occurrence of delimiters. (Output of `df` has multiple spaces if you note)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're delimiting on whitespace and not *repeated* whitespace, your columns are messed up. Try this:

```
df -kh -B 1g | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4
```

The `tr` turns all repeated spaces into single spaces, so you can cut them as you please.

Comment: I tried that and its not returning the 1st AND the 4th field!! I tried df -kh -B 1g /ws/abc-Location03 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f4 > file1.txt

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem; it should be noted that `cut` fundamentally doesn't support treating runs of multiple delimiter characters as a single delimiter, and also doesn't support specifying multi-character delimiters (hence the need for `tr -s`).

Comment: @Canzee: exactly what output are you seeing?

Comment: @whereswalden `Available
abc5-xyz04c:/root_vdm_6/t2local24/abc-Location03
93`

Comment: @whereswalden Sorry my first comment has a typo, it returned the 1st AND the 4th field.

Comment: It seems like the first line of overflowing and becoming a second line. That shouldn't happen if you're piping the output of `df` directly into `tr`. Are you copy-pasting by any chance?

Comment: @whereswalden Not sure I follow. I did `df -kh -B 1g /ws/abc-Location03 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4` And its returning `Available abc5-xyz04c:/root_vdm_6/t2local24/abc-Location03 93`

Comment: Let's continue this in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/57208/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-24705898

Answer (score 0):

For this, and many other similar problems, the shortest solution might be to use [***cuts***](http://arielf.github.io/cuts/) ("cut on steroids") which tries to fix most pain-points of `cut`.

Example:

```
$ df -kh -B 1g / | cuts 3
Used
25
```

http://arielf.github.io/cuts/